# Can Azure Data Lake Store .NET SDK read and write binary files?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-sdk-.net

The ADLS .NET SDK has some good examples for reading and creating text files.  This uses StreamReader and this shouldn't be used with binary files.  I tried using BinaryReader but have been unsuccessful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk

```
//Read file contents
using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = readStream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Can the .NET SDK create/read binary?  If so, are there any examples of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the .NET SDK create/read binary? If so, are there any examples of doing this?

Short answer is yes, please refer to the following demo code.

**Create binary File**

```
AdlsClient adlsClient = AdlsClient.CreateClient($"{datalakeAccount}.azuredatalakestore.net", clientCreds);
using (var stream = adlsClient.CreateFile("file name", IfExists.Overwrite))
{
    byte[] textByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"local file path");
    stream.Write(textByteArray, 0, textByteArray.Length);
}
```

**read binary file and write to local file**

```
using (var filesream = adlsClient.GetReadStream("1.png"))

{               
     MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
     filesream.CopyTo(memorystream);
     memorystream.Position = 0;
     File.WriteAllBytes(@"filename", memorystream.ToArray());         
}
```